# ¿Cómo refrescar el grafico de una función a medida que se va modificando una valor de la función?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy teniendo problemas con una gráfica. Agregue una opción que permite modificar un valor de la función que estoy graficando, el problema es que me hace el nuevo gráfico pero encima del anterior.
Por favor si alguien pudiera ayudarme sería genial, ya no se que más probar.

```html
<head>
  <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id='myDiv'></div>
  <input id="numb">

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">L</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var zPts = [];
    var xPts = [];
    var yPts = [];

    var L = 0.1;

    function myFunction() {

      var G = 10;
      var L = document.getElementById("numb").value;
      for (x = -3; x <= 3; x += 0.001) {
        let zdat = [];
        let ydat = [];
        let xdat = [];

        for (y = 0; y <= 0.5; y += 0.01) {
          zdat.push(2 * 0.125 * [Math.sqrt(2 / (Math.PI * (L ** 2 + (G ** 2 * y ** 2)))) * Math.exp(-2 * ((x ** 2) + 0.25) / [L ** 2 + (G ** 2 * y ** 2)])] * [Math.cosh(2 * x / (L ** 2 + (G ** 2 * y ** 2))) + Math.cos(2 * x * y * (G ** 2) / (L ** 2 + (G ** 2 * y ** 2)))]);
          ydat.push(y);
          xdat.push(x);
        }
        zPts.push(zdat);
        yPts.push(ydat);
        xPts.push(xdat);
      }

      var data = [{
        z: zPts,
        x: xPts,
        y: yPts,
        type: 'surface',
        colorscale: 'Jet',
        contours: {
          z: {
            show: true,
            usecolormap: true,
            highlightcolor: "#42f462",
            project: {
              z: true
            }
          }
        }

      }];

      var myplot = Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
      document.getElementById("myplot").innerHTML;



    }
    myFunction()
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Es imposible saber cómo ayudarte sin saber qué está pasando, no estoy viendo tu monitor. Si compartes tu código alguien podría ayudarte, de lo contrario me temo que esta pregunta sería cerrada porque parece ser imposible de poder responder.

Comment: disculpas, ahí lo agregue.

Comment: De donde sale zPts, yPts y xPts?

Comment: Las va generando, igual falta una parte que no creí necesario poner acá donde se declaran los vectores.

Comment: Limpia la gráfica anterior antes de generar la nueva.

Comment: y como hago eso ?

Comment: una consulta, aparte de esto no me deja poner el código por es más código que texto, como lo puedo se soluciona?

Comment: Utiliza un snippet, voy a editar tu pregunta para que veas como funciona. Luego si quieres cambiar el snippet va a aparecer un texto azul debajo del mismo para que lo edites, dice algo como "editar este fragmento de código". Además al usar un snippet puedes tener un preview de cómo se ve lo que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 1):

1. Si lees la documentación de la librería, vas a encontrar que para
   actualizar los datos recomiendan [`plotly.react`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/).
2. Haces una doble definición de tu variable `L`, no hagas esto.
3. Cuando sacas el `value` del input necesitas convertirlo a número para que puedas utilizarlo en tu ecuación.
4. Si tu función revisa el valor del `value` del input y luego lo asigna a L, entonces deberías de inicializa el mismo con un valor de inicio.
5. Si vas a volver a dibujar el dato necesitas "vaciar" los arrays donde guardas tus puntos de lo contrario solo vas a acumular datos nuevos constantemente.
6. Crea un gráfico vacío al inicio y luego con la función lo actualizas por medio de `plotly.react`.

```html
<head>
  <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id='myDiv'></div>
  <input id="numb">

  <button type="button" value="0.1" onclick="myFunction()">L</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var zPts = [];
    var xPts = [];
    var yPts = [];

    var L = 0.1;

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', 0);

    function myFunction() {

      var G = 10;

      zPts = [];
      xPts = [];
      yPts = [];

      L = Number(document.getElementById("numb").value);

      for (x = -3; x <= 3; x += 0.001) {
        let zdat = [];
        let ydat = [];
        let xdat = [];

        for (y = 0; y <= 0.5; y += 0.01) {
          zdat.push(2 * 0.125 * [Math.sqrt(2 / (Math.PI * (L ** 2 + (G ** 2 * y ** 2)))) * Math.exp(-2 * ((x ** 2) + 0.25) / [L ** 2 + (G ** 2 * y ** 2)])] * [Math.cosh(2 * x / (L ** 2 + (G ** 2 * y ** 2))) + Math.cos(2 * x * y * (G ** 2) / (L ** 2 + (G ** 2 * y ** 2)))]);
          ydat.push(y);
          xdat.push(x);
        }
        zPts.push(zdat);
        yPts.push(ydat);
        xPts.push(xdat);
      }

      var data = [{
        z: zPts,
        x: xPts,
        y: yPts,
        type: 'surface',
        colorscale: 'Jet',
        contours: {
          z: {
            show: true,
            usecolormap: true,
            highlightcolor: "#42f462",
            project: {
              z: true
            }
          }
        }

      }];

      Plotly.react('myDiv', data);
    }

    myFunction()
  </script>
</body>
```

Espero que las correciones te sirvan de ayuda ¡Suerte programando!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda FranAcuna, toda ayuda me viene bien.  Aunque ahora al poner un valor para L la gráfica no se modifica.

Comment: ¡Tienes razón! De hecho empecé a darle vueltas al problema porque no entendía que pasaba, al final era que no estabas reseteando los arrays donde tienes tus puntos... Por lo tanto se agregaban nuevos datos al array que estaban fuera de visión.

Comment: Muchas gracias!